# Looking for an example of CALLTHIS in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

I won't list the many many permutations I tried that did not work.

My goal is to call a subroutine that takes the caller's name as an argument.

Something like:

```
Public Sub Shape_DoubleClick(ByVal shapeName As String)
    Debug.Print "Shape_DoubleClick called for: " & shapeName
End Sub
```

But no matter what I write into the EventDblClick cell of the ShapeSheet, I do not see any activity.

I can not get anything that involves CALLTHIS to work in Visio.
Can anyone show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to call a subroutine that **takes the caller's name as an argument**.

Argument of called function must be Shape Object, not string!
Please read more in [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/callthis-function#remarks) for [CALLTHIS function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/callthis-function) description.

---

You can change your code like:

```
Public Sub Shape_DoubleClick(ShapeObj As Shape)
    MsgBox "Shape_DoubleClick called for: " & ShapeObj.Name
End Sub
```

And formula in **EventDblClick** cell must be like: `CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.Shape_DoubleClick")`

**UPDATED**:
You can combine Shape object and string arguments:

```
Public Sub Shape_DoubleClick(vsoShape As Visio.Shape, shapeName As String)
   MsgBox "Shape_DoubleClick called for: " & shapeName
End Sub
```

For run this routine use formula: `CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.Shape_DoubleClick",,NAME())`

Please read more about CALLTHIS in article [Using the CALLTHIS function in Visio](https://bvisual.net/2021/02/22/using-the-callthis-function-in-visio/) by [David J Parker](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-US/MVP/profile/6183d172-3c9a-e411-93f2-9cb65495d3c4)!